# Computer build question

Tags: discussion, faq-update-request

A new question about [computer building](https://superuser.com/questions/195203/what-are-some-good-ways-to-convert-this-old-extended-ata-system-closed) was recently closed with the "Off Topic" reason. But the close text is a bit misleading:

> Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the faq.

This question is undoubtedly about computer hardware so any newcomers might wonder what's going on.

My suggestion is that:

1. Explain that questions about building a computer is not wanted and [why](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/665/superuser-organization-for-new-computer-build-questions) in the faq
2. Add something about this in the `close as OT` text. (Not sure about this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot the note about it being akin to walking down the aisle trying to ask everybody around you which part is best for the new machine.

> This is the same as asking for shopping advice, which is off-topic

It's that "generally relate to" part which makes many users with closed questions scratch.

Of course it's all related. But it's not on-topic or on-focus for the site.

Really should be changed to be more explicit along the lines of:

> Questions on Super User are expected to help you find fixes to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the faq.